# How can I stop dropzone from removing my file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have the 'removedfile' event for dropzone configured.
But in the function, I remove the file from the server.

If the server fails to delete the file,
then I want the dropzone event to cancel deleting the file from the dropzone element window.

Is this possible?

Here is my remove code

```
this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
  //remove file from server
  if (file.status == 'success') {
    var model = {
      contractId: contractId,
      clientId: scope.currentClientId,
      fileName: file.name
    };
    scope.ajaxPost(scope.enumControllers.deleteContractAttachment, model, function(response) {
      response.error == false ? tp.showAlert(response.Message, 'success') : tp.showAlert(response.Message, 'error');;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem and I solved it.
you need to modify the source code.

1: overwrite the `removedfile` event. add remove function to Dropzone option like below:

```
new Dropzone({
      // options
      removefile: function(){
          // remove from server...
      }
});
```

2: in `removeFile` function:
    delete this code : `this.files = without(this.files, file);`

3: move `without` to `dropzone.prototype`:

```
Dropzone.prototype.without = function(list, rejectedItem) {//...}
```

last: this is my `removedfile` function(it is not a event of init function but a option of dropzone options):

```
removedfile: function (file) {
                var _ref,
                    isFileUploadSuccess = (file.status === Dropzone.SUCCESS),
                    isDeleteSuccess;
                if (isFileUploadSuccess) {
                    customOptions && typeof customOptions.removeFunc === "function" && (isDeleteSuccess = customOptions.removeFunc(file));
                }
                if ((isFileUploadSuccess && isDeleteSuccess || !isFileUploadSuccess) && file.previewElement && (_ref = file.previewElement) !== null) {
                    _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement);
                    this.files = this.without(this.files, file);
                }
                return this._updateMaxFilesReachedClass();
            }
```

`removeFunc` is my function to remove file from server by ajax ( async:false ) , so I can receive the result whether the file is successfully deleted or not;

Maybe my code is not nice, but it solve my problem.